# Search for Specific raw input python

Tags: python, search, input

So im trying to have my script check to make sure the user input is in a correct format. for example, I'm trying to get the user to input a string that looks like:

0B/4B/07

I want to make sure the script knows that the string should look exactly like that with varying numbers and letters, but is a total len of 8 characters, and the /'s are in exactly those positions. I know there should be a way to do this with the re module but i cant seem to figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: *I know there should be a way to do this with the re module* - yes, what have you attempted thus far?

Comment: something like `if len(x) == 8 and x[2] == '//' and x[5] == '//'` should do it

Comment: @TimCastelijns Which would validate `"////////"` (no need to quote `'/'` characters by doubling them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import re


    def check(word):
        pattern = "^[0-9A-Z]{2,2}/[0-9A-Z]{2,2}/[0-9A-Z]{2,2}$"

        m = re.search(pattern,word)

        if m:
         print("true")
        else :
            print("false")

#############################
    > check('0B/4B/07')   o/p true 

    >check('0B/4B/075')   o/p false
```

You can use regex for this

Or `if len(x) == 8 and x[2] == '//' and x[5] == '//'`  some thing like this as suggested by @Tim Castelijns

Answer (score 0):

The following will test that the users input matches your format with `re.search` and then use `re.findall` to assign a tuple with each of the matches to the variable `matches`. `[A-Za-z0-9]` matches any alphanumeric character, while `{2}` indicates that there should be two matches of the prior character. In addition, wraping characters in `()` indicates that you want to return them in an `re.findall`.

```
import re

text = "0B/4B/07"

def get_input(text):
    if re.search("[A-Za-z0-9]{2}/[A-Za-z0-9]{2}/[A-Za-z0-9]{2}", text):
        matches = re.findall(
                     "([A-Za-z0-9]{2})/([A-Za-z0-9]{2})/([A-Za-z0-9]{2})",
                     text
                 )[0]
        return matches
    else:
        return None
```

Usage:

```
>>> text = "0B/4B/07"
>>> get_input(text)
('0B', '4B', '07')
```

Comment: Your regexp also matches `-?/!-/+.`, a more appropriate might be `([A-z0-9]{2}/){2}[A-z0-9]{2}` which only matches alphanumerics since the OP requested that it matches varying numbers and letters between the slashes.